# show echo command string with spaces and symbols in .zshrc

Tags: string, shell, echo, config, zsh

I try to decorate .zshrc config ASCII Art like this for example. How to show all symbols with gaps in string in a correct and compact way?

```
 __         __
/  \.-"""-./  \
\    -   -    /
 |   o   o   |
 \  .-'''-.  /
  '-\__Y__/-'
     `---`
```

```
echo " __         __ "
echo "/  \.-"""-./  \"
echo "\    -   -    /"
echo " |   o   o   | "
echo " \  .-'''-.  / "
echo "  '-\__Y__/-'  "
echo "     `---`     "
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMKtS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a quoted here document.

```
cat <<'EOF'
 __         __
/  \.-"""-./  \
\    -   -    /
 |   o   o   |
 \ .-'''-.  / 
  '-\__Y__/-'
     `---`
EOF
```